# backend throwing 302 for https pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, https, varnish, http-status-code-302

I'm working on a web app implemented in RoR with varnish on top.

The problem is that Whenever we hit a url from an https page , the backend throws 302. For eg: I am on page "https://beta.example.com". Now if I hit any link from this page the backend throws 302 to the same url (this causes infinite loop).

Basically the backend throws 302 (to itself) which gets cached in Varnish.

How can I figure out whats wrong and hence fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look in the logs to find out who is responsible for the 302 redirect?

Comment: Please, at least provide your VCL configuration... and request trace if posible.